# Can logistic pipes craft items when an item comes into my system?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have 3 logistic crafting tables setup to turn cobblestone into triple condensed cobblestone when I request it. Can I make my system automatically craft it when cobble enters my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to put a supplier pipe on the back which is requesting infinite Triple condensed cobblestone, and it seems to be working fine, normal cobble goes into my cobble barrel, then as soon as there is enough for a triple block (729 cobblestone), the triple gets crafted and stored.

Answer (score 1):

By rightclicking with a wrench, you're able to assign items to a basic logistics pipe. The specific items will then be routed to the pipe if they enter your system.